# JSON object - too large that Angular parse is super slow?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

one part of my app has become increadibly slow.
I POST some data to the server which then runs some calculations. I can track when the PHP is done. Here's the timelime:

POST -> PHP Done ~ 1min. -> DONE in console ~ 3min.

```
$http.post(requestURL, {'someData':data}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('DONE');
    }
}
```

Why is that? I calculated the size of the returned data to 23kb `JSON.stringify(data).length / 1024` 
My `PHP` only sends `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and then the object.

Seems that it takes the `success` branch a while to move forward after it received the data. Data integrity is OK, hence the values make sense. However, it's super slow.

To clarify, I am worried about the time between the `PHP` script sends the return and the client jumps into the success branch, not the calculation. However, if it helps, say it calculates PI :).

Comment: Suggest you do some profiling on server. No way for us to know what your calculations are about